# Writing a function that takes in a string and prints out the characters in order of ASCII code

Tags: c++

I have to write a function called alphabetize that returns void and takes in one string and prints out each character of the given string ordered by ASCII code lowest to highest.

For example:    alphabetize("Hello World!") prints " !HWdellloor" 
(note the space before "!HWdellloor"; it is in the proper order)

Completely confused on where to start. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::sort()`, and read it. Now, use what you just learned to sort your string. The End.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the string as a parameter(char*).In function, use strlen to calculate the length of the string, sort the string array, and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Include **bits/stdc++.h** and
**using namespace std**;

Try the below code:

```
void alphabetize (string &str) 
{ 
sort (str.begin(), str.end()); 

cout << str; 
}
```

Comment: Don't include **bits/stdc++.h** and don't add **using namespace std;**. For `std::sort`, use `#include <algorithm>`; for `std::string`, use `#include <string>`; for `std::cout`, use `#include <iostream>`. Those are standard headers. `bits/stdc++.h` is not.